# Are goroutines garbage collected together with their channels?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

Imagine the following code:

```
func waitForOneOfTwoProcesses() {

    c := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        c<-true
    }()
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        c<-true
    }()
    <-c

}
```

Does this leak a channel and a goroutine or does Go recognize that `c` is gone and the goroutine can exit?

Would the answer be any different if the channel had a buffer size of 2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the channel is unbuffered, then one of the anonymous functions will not return.  The program leaks a goroutine and channel.

If the channel has a buffer size greater than or equal to one, then both of the  anonymous functions will return. The resources used by the goroutines and channel will be reclaimed.

A buffer size of one is sufficient to prevent the leak. The function `waitForOneOfTwoProcesses` receives one of the values sent to `c`.  The second value sent to `c` is buffered in the channel (which is collected by the GC).

Comment: So the write to the channel blocks, even though the channel is out of scope and can never be read from again. I wonder if that's a bug or a feature.

Comment: Yes, send will block even though there is no receiver. The runtime could be written to detect when the application is done receiving on a channel in this specific example, but it's not something that the runtime can detect in general.

Comment: As a note, there is a "non-blocking send" available as well, which solves this exact problem - you'd set the buffer on the channel to 1 and each would send without blocking.  Described in more detail here: https://blog.golang.org/go-concurrency-patterns-timing-out-and