# websocket client onmessage broken after refreshing browser

Tags: javascript, go, websocket

I have a `Websocket` server written in `go` with package `github.com/gorilla/websocket`.

The server has 2 loops for receiving and sending messages.  The implementation of the http handler looks like the following:

```
upgrader, errChan := websocket.Upgrader{}, make(chan error)

ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

// incoming messages

go func() { 
    for {
        message := Message{}
        if err := ws.ReadJSON(&message); err != nil {
            errChan <- err
        }
        handleMessage(message)
    }
}()

// outgoing messages 

go func() { 
    for {
        message := <-global.outgoingMessage
        if err = ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, message); err != nil {
            errChan <- err
        }
    }
}()

err = <- errChan
ws.Close()
```

The client application uses React and the app uses the message to as a state.   When the app is launched, the websocket connection is established and the onopen callback fires a request for the initial data.  The response is caught by onmessage which is used for the app state.  The implementation looks like the following:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/app")

ws.onerror = function(err) {
    alert(err)
}
ws.onmessage = function(m) {
    var state = JSON.parse(m.data)
    global.app.setState(state) 
}
ws.onopen = function() { 
    ws.send('{"type":"init"}')
}
```

With this setup, what I've been noticing is the first time I fire up the app and browse to the page everything works fine.  Once I refresh the browser, it no longer works.  I can call `ws.send('{"type":"init"}')` and see the response sent by the server but the `onmessage` callback doesn't get fired.  After several more tries of calling `ws.send('{"type":"init"}')` the `onmessage` eventually gets called once and the app state gets loaded.  If I kill and restart the app, the same behaviour occurs.

Thoughts?

Comment: The application leaks goroutines. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090545/are-goroutines-garbage-collected-together-with-their-channels) for an explanation.  Do multiple output groutines receive from `global.outgoingMessage`? If so, what ensures that enough messages are sent to `global.outgoingMessage` to satisfy all of the running output goroutines?

Comment: @MellowMarmot you're right.  `global.outgoingMessage` is only receiving from within this handler, but it is a global channel so when the browser websocket connection is refreshed, the previous connection is still listening on the channel.  if u post the answer i'll accept it.  thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all output goroutines receive from the single channel `global.outgoingMessage` and that insufficient messages are sent to this channel to satisfy all running output goroutines.

If the intent of the application is to broadcast to all connected clients, then I suggest following the hub pattern in the [Gorilla chat example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat#chat-example).

Aside: The application leaks goroutines. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090545/are-goroutines-garbage-collected-together-with-their-channels) for an explanation.